# How can I JUnit test "printlist"?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have been staring at this code for quite some time now and I really can't figure out how and what to do for its JUnit testing.

```
static void printList(OrderedIntList list) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.orderedIntegerList.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(list.orderedIntegerList[i]);
        if (i != list.orderedIntegerList.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

This code is from a utility class called `orderedIntList`, which is an array list.

Comment: my apologies, kind sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... think about the contracts of this method: What does it promise? It promises to print a list of integers, separated by a comma, and inside of brackets. So, you could specify this in a unit test.

**Edit2:** Just in case you fancy unit testing whether the list is printed in order: I would not consider this a property of the `printList` method. This property should be tested in the methods that modify the `OrderedIntList`.

Write a fixture for some Lists with the string that you expect to be printed. Don't forget the corner case: An empty list. Then, maybe a list of size 1 and one of size 10.

To check what has been printed, you can create a new `PrintStream`, and set the value of `System.out`, by calling `System.setOut`. Do this at the beginning of each test, and don't forget to reset `System.out` (so don't forget to store its original value). The `PrintStream` you use need not be fancy: You simply must be able to compare the printed stream. You may want to consider using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) for that matter.

**Edit:**

For example, the following code tests whether the list containing the sole element `4`, actually prints the string `"[4]\n"`:

```
@Test
public void aListOfSizeOneShouldPrintTheElementWithinBrackets() {
    /* Setup */
    final StringBuffer printStream = new StringBuffer();
    PrintStream mockedOut = mock(PrintStream.class);
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            printStream.append(invocation.getArguments()[0].toString());
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockedOut).print(any());
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            printStream.append(invocation.getArguments()[0].toString());
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockedOut).print(anyString());
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            printStream.append(invocation.getArguments()[0].toString()).append("\n");
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockedOut).println(any());
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            printStream.append(invocation.getArguments()[0].toString()).append("\n");
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockedOut).println(anyString());
    PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
    System.setOut(mockedOut);
    /* the actual test */
    ArrayList<Integer> listWithOneElement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listWithOneElement.add(4);
    OrderedIntList list = new OrderedIntList(listWithOneElement);
    OrderedIntList.printList(list);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(printStream.toString(), is("[4]\n"));
    /* Teardown - reset System.out */
    System.setOut(originalOut);
}
```

Note that you probably want to extract the setup- and the teardown part to use it in other tests and to make your test readable. If I am not mistaken, JUnit provides functionality to add code that gets invoked before and after each test execution if you specify it with an `@Before` and `@After` annotation.

Obviously, you do not necessarily need Mockito to achieve this. You can also write a class that implements `PrintStream` and stores the printed strings. In this case, Mockito simply allows you to ignore all the methods you do not care about (i.e., you do not need to implement the whole `PrintStream` interface)

A small sidenote on the duplication of the stubing: We need to stub both methods, `print` and `println`, because both are used. Also, because of overriding, `print(String x)` is not the same as `print(Object x)`, so we need to stub them both.

Comment: Sure. I'll create an example and edit it into my answer

Comment: how can this code be compressed? for comparison purposes. (println to array kind of comparison.)

Comment: I don't quite understand this question. What do you mean by "compressed"? And what do you mean by "array kind of comparison"? I don't think you can make the test setup much smaller. Your code at least uses `print(String)`, `println(String)`, and `print(Object)` (or `print(int)`, if you are using ints instead of Integers), so you have to at least stub these three methods. I don't see a way around that.

Comment: i was using metaphors. im sorry about that. i was referring to complex to simple. thank you for the help. :)

Comment: I am still not 100% sure what you are asking, but I'll try to give an answer: Testing this code is overly complex, because your method in fact does two independent things: It **converts** the `OrderedIntList` into a `String` **and** it **prints** the list to stdout. This can be made more simple by separating those two concerns. Testing of the string conversions is **independent on static** variables and you don't have to mock anything, while printing becomes in fact a single statement which you can test using `Mockito.verify`.

Answer (score 0):

@Kulu Limpa answer is correct but much more complicated than the actual implementation, because you need some mocking.

if you refactor your code to

```
static void printList(OrderedIntList list) {
    System.out.println(toString(list));
}

static String toString(OrderedIntList list) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println(toString(list));
    result.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.orderedIntegerList.length; i++) {
        result.append(list.orderedIntegerList[i]);
        if (i != list.orderedIntegerList.length - 1) {
            result.append(", ");
        }
    }
    result.append("]");
    return result.toString();
}
```

testing should be much easier:

```
@Test
public void aListOfSizeOneShouldPrintTheElementWithinBrackets() {
    ArrayList<Integer> listWithOneElement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listWithOneElement.add(4);
    OrderedIntList list = new OrderedIntList(listWithOneElement);

    String result = OrderedIntList.toString(list);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(result, is("[4]"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) has a JUnit rule called StandardOutputStreamLog. With this rule you are able to test your code, that writes to `System.out`:

```
public void MyTest {
    @Rule
    public final StandardOutputStreamLog log = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        OrderedIntList list = ...
        printList(list);
        assertEquals("[1,2,3,4]", log.getLog());
    }
}
```